# How does the moment of inertia of a pendulum changes if you add a mass on the free spinning end?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Say the initial moment of inertia of the (physical) pendulum was (ML²)/12.
How does that result change once you put a mass anywhere on the pendulum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial moment of inertia $ \frac{ML^2}{12} $ of the pendulum is about an axis/center of rotation. If you add a point object with mass $ m_{obj} $ at a distance $ 
r_{obj} $ from the axis/center, you can write the equations as shown below. Let $ P $ denote the set of points in the original pendulum.

$$
\begin{align}
I_{init} &= \sum_{i\in P}{m_ir_i^2} = \frac{ML^2}{12}\\
I_{new} &= \sum_{i\in P}{m_ir_i^2} + m_{obj}r_{obj}^2\\
&= \frac{ML^2}{12} + m_{obj}r_{obj}^2
\end{align}
$$

If it involves any change of axis, you can also use the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem).

Comment: so if the axis is changed, for example, to be at a pivot point and at the same time you add mass on one end the new moment of inertia will be (ML^2)/12 + MR^2 (being R the distance to the new pivot point and M the total mass of the pendulum without the added mass) + mobj(r^2) ? Or should M be the TOTAL mass of the pendulum AND to added mass on one extreme?

Comment: M is the initial mass of the pendulum i.e. without the added mass

Answer (score 0):

I as the bob of simple pendulum is like a solid cylinder so by adding more mass to it increases its moment of inertia by amount mr2